# Add SAN or Local disk to already provisioned Server in Softlayer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am new to the softlayer rest APIs. We have a requirement where user will be allowed to add a additional SAN or Local Disk to the existing provisioned server in softlayer. For that I was referring to the [REST API guide](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject) Our project is build on `Ruby on Rails` and we are using `softlayer_api` gem and so I was looking at the [api ruby doc](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/softlayer/softlayer-api-ruby-client). But none of these links helped me. Are there any ruby examples for `adding a disk` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following example to `upgrade a Virtual Guest in order to add a disk`:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'softlayer_api'

# Your SoftLayer API username.
SL_API_USERNAME = 'set me'

# Your SoftLayer API key.
SL_API_KEY = 'set me'


# Set the server id that you wish to upgrade.
server_id = 17850400

# Set the new item price id to upgrade the VSI
price_id = 51733  # 10 GB (SAN) "categoryCode": "guest_disk1", "name": "Second Disk"

# Order Template with all new item configurations
object_template = {'packageId'=> 0,
                   'prices'=> [
                       {
                           'id'=> price_id
                       }
                   ],
                   'virtualGuests'=> [
                       {
                           'id'=> server_id
                       }
                   ],
                   'properties'=> [
                       {
                           'name'=> 'NOTE_GENERAL',
                           'value'=> 'Adding a SAN disk'
                       },
                       {
                           'name'=> 'MAINTENANCE_WINDOW',
                           'value'=> 'now'
                       }
                   ],
                   'complexType'=> 'SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest_Upgrade'
}

softlayer_client = SoftLayer::Client.new(:username => SL_API_USERNAME,
                                         :api_key => SL_API_KEY)
product_order_service = softlayer_client.service_named('SoftLayer_Product_Order')

begin
  result = product_order_service.verifyOrder(object_template)
  puts 'Result:  '
  puts result.inspect
rescue Exception => e
  puts 'Unable to add the new SAN Disk ...'
  $stdout.print(e.inspect)
end
```

**Note:** Once your script is ready, please change from `verifyOrder` to `placeOrder`.

To get valid prices for upgrade, please review:

[SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getUpgradeItemPrices](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getUpgradeItemPrices)

**References:**

[SoftLayer_Product_Order](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order)

[SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest_Upgrade](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest_Upgrade)

[upgrade_examples](https://softlayer.github.io/python/upgrade_examples/)

Comment: I will try running the code pasted above and will get back to you

Comment: This is the `Order Template {"complexType"=>"SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest_Upgrade", "virtualGuests"=>[{"id"=>12345}], "properties"=>[{"name"=>"MAINTENANCE_WINDOW", "value"=>"2016-05-18T18:14:05+00:00"}], "prices"=>[{"id"=>25396}, {"id"=>35237}]} ` For that I got exception --> 
`XMLRPC::FaultException: Unable to add 30 GB (SAN) because a Second Disk price has already been added.`  What might be the reason ?

Comment: @AnupamK, maybe the Virtual Guest that you want to upgrade has a `second disk` and some of the `item prices` belong to a ‘second disk’. To confirm this, please execute the following Rest request in order to know the items of your Virtual Guest: `https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[server_id]/getBillingItem?objectMask=mask[id,orderItem[id, order[id,items]]]`.  If your VSI has a second disk, you will able to add from third disk.

Comment: hi when I run this `https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/19304505/getBillingItem?objectMask=mask[id,orderItem[id,%20order[id,items]]]` I see there is only 1 disk item listed and that is `<categoryCode>guest_disk0</categoryCode>
<description>25 GB (SAN)</description>`

Comment: when i run the command `lsblk` on machine i see that there is 
` NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
**xvda    202:0    0   25G  0 disk**
├─xvda1 202:1    0  256M  0 part /boot
└─xvda2 202:2    0 24.8G  0 part /
xvdb    202:16   0    2G  0 disk 
└─xvdb1 202:17   0    2G  0 part [SWAP]
**xvdc    202:32   0   30G  0 disk** 
xvdh    202:112  0   64M  0 disk 
└─xvdh1 202:113  0   61M  0 part`

Comment: I tried again with below 
Order Template `{"complexType"=>"SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest_Upgrade", "virtualGuests"=>[{"id"=>19304505}], "properties"=>[{"name"=>"MAINTENANCE_WINDOW", "value"=>"2016-05-19T03:40:12+00:00"}], "prices"=>[{"id"=>25396}, {"id"=>34869}]} ` but i see the same exception `Unable to add 10 GB (SAN) because a Second Disk price has already been added`

Comment: I think `categoryCode` or `id` tag for the `prices` is missing , so it always tries to add disk to only 1 default location :)

Comment: You are right. I executed some tests and the `categoryCode` helps us to decide what disk we will add. Also I had an error message: `"error": "A current price was provided for the upgrade order. Please send a different price to upgrade the item.`. And reviewing the `virtual Guest` using this request: `https:// api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/19304505/getObject?objectMask=mask[id,upgradeRequest[id,order[items]]]`, we can notice an upgrade was executed in that server where some disks were added. This is reason of this error message. Please take into account. Regards.